# Determining identity for connections with socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io, nestjs

What fields could I use on the connection socket to identify a user in business logic? Imagine a browser game with rooms/lobbies.

You ideally want to allow users to reconnect if something temporarily happens to their connection, so `socket.id` wouldn't really work.

On the other hand, persisting IP addresses sounds wrong (`socket.handshake.address`).

What other (combination) of fields could I use that persists through disconnects? Could the hash of the IP address alongside `socket.handshake.address.user-agent` work? (this allows users to connect from multiple browsers, but I think that's fine)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the authentication logic, you can save the `userId` once the user is connected to the lobby, and store it while the room/lobby exists.

If you see the user trying to connect to the room but you have their ID, you can reconnect them instead. In my case, I have the class `Player` with a property `isTemporaryLeft` (in my case, the player is given some time to reconnect).

When the user disconnects, I set the property to true. When they reconnect I simply find them in the `players` array, set isTemporaryLeft false, and emit reconnect event with all needed data.